# Remove DNS A record in Active Directory from Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, active-directory, likewise-open

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server that I joined to AD using PBIS, via its domainjoin-cli utility, then created a DNS record in AD using its update-dns utility as well.

Now I need to leave the domain, as well as delete the DNS record from AD. I could successfully leave the domain using domainjoin-cli, but still don't know how I can delete the DNS record from AD!

Any ideas, even if with an alternate method than PBIS?

Comment: You can try using Kerberos and nsupdate but I assume your key is already revoked. Ask an administrator to remove it for you.

Comment: What key? I don't get it.